# Dynamically add and remove list items in an IPython widget

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I'm trying to achieve a basic todo list app in Ipython Jupyter Notebook using `ipywidgets`.

I can easily achieve the functionality of adding items to my list, however, I can't properly handle removing of existing items if the 'Remove' button is clicked. The entire code is run in a single cell.

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import VBox, HBox, Text, Button
from IPython.display import display

todo = []

def completed_sentence(sentence): 
    """ To display existing notes with a 'Remove' button """
    sentenceField = Text(value=sentence)
    removeButton = Button(description='Remove',
                          button_style='danger')
    return HBox([sentenceField, removeButton])

def render_sentences(_):
    """ To update the view """
    global a,b
    if a.value != '':
        todo.append(a.value)
    a.value = ''
        todoWidget.children = tuple\
            ([VBox([VBox([completed_sentence(each) 
                          for each in todo]),
                    HBox([a, b])])])
    
# Setting up a basic view- with an empty field and a button
a = widgets.Text(value='')
b = widgets.Button(description='Add')                                 
b.on_click(render_sentences)

todoWidget = widgets.HBox([a, b])
display(todoWidget)
```

Now, in order to enable the removal of sentences, I update the definition of the function `completed_sentence` as follows:

```py
def completed_sentence(sentence):
    """ To display existing notes """
    def remove_sentence(_):
        global render_sentences
        try:
            if todo.index(sentenceField.value) >= 0:
                todo.remove(sentenceField.value)
                render_sentences()
        except:
            return 
                
    sentenceField = Text(value=sentence)
    removeButton = Button(description='Remove', button_style='danger')
    removeButton.on_click(remove_sentence)
    return HBox([sentenceField, removeButton])
```

But now, this has the issue that its call to `render_sentences` is ignored! What is the optimal way to deal with such a kind of 'reactive' programming, if you will, using Ipython Widgets.

Answer (score 1):

Updating the definition of `completed_sentence` seems to do the job. But it still remains a mystery why the original definition didn't work.

```py
def completed_sentence(sentence):
    def remove_sentence(_):
        global render_sentences
        try:
            if todo.index(sentenceField.value) >= 0:
                todo.remove(sentenceField.value)
        except:
            pass
        render_sentences(_)
                
    sentenceField = Text(value=sentence)
    removeButton = Button(description='Remove', button_style='danger')
    removeButton.on_click(remove_sentence)
    sentence_view = HBox([sentenceField, removeButton])
    return sentence_view
```